# Corrupt/Invalid Invoice for ApplePay order using Mollie

Tags: magento2, apple-pay

We had an issue where some orders that paid using ApplePay would come in with broken invoices. (This issue was 100% of the time for some clients, and sporadic for others).
It seems to be around using ApplePay in "Direct" mode. (Store > Configuration > Mollie | Payment methods > ApplePay > Integration Type)

However it was common across all order thats `amount_paid` would always be null on the order.
To determine if you are having the same issue you can check the last 7 days orders with

```sql
select so.entity_id, so.increment_id, sop.method, so.grand_total, sop.amount_paid, sop.last_trans_id from sales_order as so
  left join sales_order_payment as sop on so.entity_id = sop.parent_id
  where so.created_at > date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) 
    and sop.method = 'mollie_methods_applepay'
    and sop.amount_paid is null
  order by so.entity_id desc;
```

If there are any records you have the same issue.
Whilst the order is in this state:

- unable to credit the order as Magento believes there is an outstanding amount
- Current invoice's totals don't match order
- Still able to invoice the order (even though the customer will have been charged the correct amount)

Answer (score 0):

**The Fix**

1. Ensure you have [cweagans/composer-patches](https://packagist.org/packages/cweagans/composer-patches) installed
2. Add the following to composer.json

```json
"extra": {
      "patches": {
          "mollie/magento2": {
              "apple pay order invoice issue": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zero1limited/magento2-patches/master/patches/Mollie_applepay_invoice_broken.patch"
          }
      }
  }
```

3. `composer install` / `composer install --no-dev`

You should then be able to test ApplePay.
(N.B at the time of writing it isn't possible to place a test ApplePay order through Mollie, so it needs to be a valid card, but it can be placed on a test system in live mode)

**The explanation**
Mollie was/is altering the order in two different processes at the same time, and then not synchronizing the data correctly.

From this log

```
START: /mollie/checkout/redirect/paymentToken/XXXXX
START: /mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX
Mollie\Payment\Model\Mollie::processTransactionForOrder [{},"webhook"] [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Mollie\Payment\Model\Client\Payments::processTransaction  [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:336 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:343 payment status: "paid" [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:344 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:352 amount: 12.94, currency: USD, order amount: {"currency":"USD","value":"12.94"} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:359 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:361 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:364 settlement amount: {"value":"9.86","currency":"GBP"} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::pay [{}] [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::setAmountPaid [12.94] [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:380 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:382 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:405 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Client/Payments.php:418 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Mollie.php:370 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Mollie.php:374 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Mollie.php:380 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/mollie/magento2/Model/Mollie.php:382 payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":12.94} [/mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX]
END: /mollie/checkout/webhook/?isAjax=1&orderId=XXXXX
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/redirect/paymentToken/XXXXX]
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::save payment: {"amount_authorized":null,"amount_paid":null} [/mollie/checkout/redirect/paymentToken/XXXXX]
END: /mollie/checkout/redirect/paymentToken/XXXXX
```

(request url in the [])
We can see that the "/mollie/checkout/redirect/" starts. (loads the order)
Then "mollie/checkout/webhook" starts, updates the order and finishes.
Then "/mollie/checkout/redirect" saves it's copy of the order removing the data set by the webhook request.

To get around this I've forced a reload of the order, after the "create payment" method is sent to Mollie. (I've not dug too deep, but it looks like that ->createPayment() actually triggers the webhook request, and will wait for the webhook request to complete before proceeding.